# How to filter custom post type (CPT) with custom fields to display/hide in divi blog module?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, divi

I'm trying to implement Show/Hide functionality on Custom Post Type (CPT) with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin in Divi Blog module.
I want to be able to show only those CPT that have True value set in ACF field named 'show'.

I'm using

Theme: Divi

Plugin for custom fields in post: ACF - Advanced Custom Fields

I created Divi Child Theme (CT).

I registered Custom Post Type (CPT) by putting it in functions.php of a CT.

I installed and activated Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) by WP Engine.
I created Field Group with 3 Custom Fields and I'm successfully showing values of two of them (text field and date picker)

All good till here.

Now the problem: I created third ACF called 'show'. It is True/False field. It is meant to be used to mark if current CPT should be displayed on the frontend or not.

I'm displaying all CPTs in Divi's Blog module which has conditions under Advanced but can't find an option to display based on value in 'show' field.

Searching for a solution I found a suggestion to add the following code to a CT's functions.php:

```
function filter_CPT_by_custom_field( $query ) {
    // Check if we are on the frontend and the main query
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Check if the current post type is the New Custom Post Type
        if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'new_CPT' ) { // Make sure to replace 'new_CPT' with the actual slug of your New Custom Post Type
            // Filter posts by the custom field value 
            $meta_query = array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'show',
                    'value'   => 1, // Set this to the value of 'Yes' in your yes/no field
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            );
            
            // Modify the query to include the custom field filter
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_CPT_by_custom_field' );
```

That doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion how colud this Show/Hide functionality on CPT with ACF in Divi Blog module be implemented. Is there any other better approach?

Comment: When registering the custom post type, did you set `'capability_type'   => 'new_CPT'`? Otherwise, the default is set to post.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. I used Meta Box WordPress Custom Post Type Generator  (https://metabox.io/post-type-generator/). As Capability type I checked Post, so I have   'capability_type'     => 'post' now in code generated. Think I should use 'capability_type'   => 'new_CPT' ?

Comment: @DevTurtle
I tried changing `'capability_type'   => 'post'` to `'capability_type'   => 'new_CPT'` and it still doesn't work. I still shows all CPTs in Divi's blog module, no matter if they have ACF field named 'show' checked or not.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but has nothing to do with `capability_type`. The problem most likely is in the `query->is_main_query()` check in your `if` statement. The Divi blog module is not the main query. The main query is the page the module *appears* on. Try removing that check, and then do `var_dump( $query );` This will give you some information that you can use to change the query. Also, is your post type registered as `new_CPT`? You might want to consider changing that to something more meaningful.